# convert dict to numPy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a json file

```
{"id": 103, "data": [{"point": [10, 20], "sp": 2}, {"point": [20, 20], "sp": 3}, {"point": [10, 20], "sp": 0}, {"point": [30, 20], "sp": 0}]}
```

I am trying to convert this json in to numPy array which has only col "sp"

I tried

```
numpy_2d_arrays = np.array( list(item.sp) for item in filejson["data"])
print(numpy_2d_arrays)
```

which return <generator object speedVariance.. at 0x11421dba0>

how can I read all "sp" data point in single array using numpy from json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [5]: a
Out[5]:
{'id': 103,
 'data': [{'point': [10, 20], 'sp': 2},
  {'point': [20, 20], 'sp': 3},
  {'point': [10, 20], 'sp': 0},
  {'point': [30, 20], 'sp': 0}]}

In [10]: A = np.array([i["sp"] for i in a["data"]])

In [11]: A[A!=0]
Out[11]: array([2, 3])
```

OR

```
In [12]: np.array([i["sp"] for i in a["data"] if i["sp"]])
Out[12]: array([2, 3])
```

Comment: I also want to filter zeros from the response

Comment: second option is giving the wrong sum of array if I have floats  I tried that ...but A[A!=0] work for me.

Comment: If you remove `[]` in list comprehension, it's a generator. And list comprehensions are result in generator objects if we don't add `[]`

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonData = {"id": 103, "data": [{"point": [10, 20], "sp": 2}, {"point": [20, 20], "sp": 3}, {"point": [10, 20], "sp": 0}, {"point": [30, 20], "sp": 0}]}

numpy_2d_arrays = np.array([item['sp'] for item in jsonData['data']])

print(numpy_2d_arrays)
```